# How to disable tomcat capture log?

Tags: java, tomcat, heap-memory, eclipse-mat

I have tried to analyze java heap memory dump with MAT.
Then I found org.apache.tomcat.util.log.CaptureLog objects taking high memory from heap. How do I stop this or disable CaptureLog.
[Mat screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g77PP.png)

Comment: So you are analyze the heap memory dump for `tomcat`? In your screenshot, the `SystemLogHandler` is used to capture log so IMHO, if you want to kill these `CaptureLog` objects you should stop tomcat logging which is a really bad idea.

Comment: You are redirecting system.out and system.err to file or other resource. So that `SystemLogHandler` becomes the top in the MAT.